# Mapbox looses popups when switching between satellite and street view

Tags: mapbox

On Mapbox street map view we are drawing a geo json line and placing popups at each of the waypoints.

When switching from street map view the satellite view the waypoints disappear.

The attached fiddle contains both the style layers for street map and satellite so that you can switch between the two and see the information change for satellite.

What is the reason for this? How do we get the waypoints to appear on satellite view.

https://jsfiddle.net/Profiler/a0wemkjz/1/

````
                        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2xvbmc0MCIsImEiOiJjazNpeXV3a3MwY2Y4M2pxbGFybjZ5MTM4In0.HNQRjQR4y5V1koLlpenKUw';
                        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                            container: 'map',
                          style: 'mapbox://styles/clong40/ckbdypecg2ev71jqzc0xhdx54', //streetmap view, below is satelite view
                         // style: 'mapbox://styles/clong40/ckd74lwfm0l7f1is3iys2s6qx',
                            center:  [3.1428,39.8669],
                            zoom: 7
                        });
                        
                        // Add geolocate control to the map.
                        map.addControl(
                            new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
                                positionOptions: {
                                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                                },
                                trackUserLocation: true
                                },
                                ),'bottom-right'
                            );
                            
                        /* Creates start point marker and listens to drag event */
                        var el = document.createElement('img');
                        el.src = '/assets/images/letter_s.png';
                        var startMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el,{draggable: true}).setLngLat([3.1428,39.8669]).addTo(map);
                        function onStartDragEnd() { var lngLat = this.getLngLat();$("#start").val(lngLat.lat.toFixed(4)+','+lngLat.lng.toFixed(4));}
                        startMarker.on('dragend', onStartDragEnd);
                        
                        /* Creates end point marker and listens to drag event */
                        var el = document.createElement('img');
                        el.src = '/assets/images/letter_e.png';
                        var endMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el,{draggable: true}).setLngLat([4.0812,40.0724]).addTo(map);
                        function onEndDragEnd() { var lngLat = this.getLngLat();$("#end").val(lngLat.lat.toFixed(4)+','+lngLat.lng.toFixed(4));}
                        endMarker.on('dragend', onEndDragEnd);
                        
                        /* Let's also listen to start and end text boxes to sync back with markers */
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('#start').change(function(){if(!this.value) return; var parts = this.value.split(',');startMarker.setLngLat([parts[1].trim(),parts[0].trim()]);});
                            $('#end').change(function(){if(!this.value) return; var parts = this.value.split(',');endMarker.setLngLat([parts[1].trim(),parts[0].trim()]);});
                        });
                            
                        map.on('load', function() {
                            map.addSource('route', {
                                'type': 'geojson',
                                'data': {
                                    'type': 'Feature',
                                    'properties': {},
                                    'geometry': {
                                        'type': 'LineString',
                                        'coordinates': [
                                                                                [3.1428091990252,39.866845647036],
                                                                                [3.14265625,39.866640625],
                                                                                [3.1425,39.8665625],
                                                                                [3.141875,39.8671875],
                                                                                [3.14375,39.869375],
                                                                                [3.2,39.91],
                                                                                [3.89,40.08],
                                                                                [4.0812,40.0724],
                                                                                ]
                                    }
                                }
                            });


                            map.addLayer({
                                'id': 'route',
                                'type': 'line',
                                'source': 'route',
                                'layout': {
                                    'line-join': 'round',
                                    'line-cap': 'round'
                                },
                                'paint': {
                                    'line-color': '#333399',
                                    'line-width': 4
                                }
                            });
                        });


                        //add markers

                        map.on('load', function() {
                        map.addSource('places', {
                            'type': 'geojson',
                            'data': {
                                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                                "features": [
                                                                                            {
                                        "type": "Feature",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "icon": "information",
                                            "icon-allow-overlap": true,
                                            "iconSize": "15"
                                        },
                                        "geometry": {
                                            "type": "Point",
                                            "coordinates": [3.1428091990252,39.866845647036]
                                        }
                                    },                                                                      {
                                        "type": "Feature",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "icon": "information",
                                            "icon-allow-overlap": true,
                                            "iconSize": "15"
                                        },
                                        "geometry": {
                                            "type": "Point",
                                            "coordinates": [3.1425,39.8665625]
                                        }
                                    },                                                                      {
                                        "type": "Feature",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "icon": "information",
                                            "icon-allow-overlap": true,
                                            "iconSize": "15"
                                        },
                                        "geometry": {
                                            "type": "Point",
                                            "coordinates": [3.14375,39.869375]
                                        }
                                    },                                                                      {
                                        "type": "Feature",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "icon": "information",
                                            "icon-allow-overlap": true,
                                            "iconSize": "15"
                                        },
                                        "geometry": {
                                            "type": "Point",
                                            "coordinates": [3.89,40.08]
                                        }
                                    },                                   
                                ]
                            }
                        });
                        // Add a layer showing the places.
                        map.addLayer({
                            'id': 'places',
                            'type': 'symbol',
                            'source': 'places',
                            'layout': {
                                'icon-image': 'information',
                                'icon-size': 0.10,
                                'icon-allow-overlap': true
                            }
                        });

                        // When a click event occurs on a feature in the places layer, open a popup at the
                        // location of the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
                        map.on('click', 'places', function(e) {
                            var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
                            var description = e.features[0].properties.description;

                            // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
                            // copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
                            // over the copy being pointed to.
                            while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
                                coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
                            }

                            new mapboxgl.Popup()
                                .setLngLat(coordinates)
                                .setHTML(description)
                                .addTo(map);
                        });

                        // Change the cursor to a pointer when the mouse is over the places layer.
                        map.on('mouseenter', 'places', function() {
                            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
                        });

                        // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
                        map.on('mouseleave', 'places', function() {
                            map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
                        });
                    });


                        map.addControl(
                            new MapboxGeocoder({
                                accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
                                mapboxgl: mapboxgl
                            }), 'top-left'
                        );


            

                        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({attributionControl: false})
                        .addControl(new mapboxgl.AttributionControl({
                        compact: true
                        }));

                        var canvas = map.getCanvasContainer();

                        map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'bottom-right');

               ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the console when I switch to the satellite style, I see this:

> Image "information" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have
> added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your
> style. You can provide missing images by listening for the
> "styleimagemissing" map event.

This is referring to `map.addSource('places', ...)` where you set `"icon": "information"`

Using the styles API, you can check for the different sprites your styles have: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-a-sprite-image-or-json

you can see in the [sprites for your first style](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/clong40/ckbdypecg2ev71jqzc0xhdx54/sprite?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2xvbmc0MCIsImEiOiJjazNpeXV3a3MwY2Y4M2pxbGFybjZ5MTM4In0.HNQRjQR4y5V1koLlpenKUw) that you have a sprite called "information".

this is missing from your [satellite style](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/clong40/ckd74lwfm0l7f1is3iys2s6qx/sprite?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2xvbmc0MCIsImEiOiJjazNpeXV3a3MwY2Y4M2pxbGFybjZ5MTM4In0.HNQRjQR4y5V1koLlpenKUw)

in your JSFiddle, I swapped all references of "information" to "information-15" (a sprite that exists in both styles), and changed the icon-size to 1 in your addLayer and was able to switch between the styles and have the icons appear in both

```
map.addSource('places', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "icon": "information-15",
          "icon-allow-overlap": true,
          "iconSize": "15"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [3.1428091990252, 39.866845647036]
        }
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "icon": "information-15",
          "icon-allow-overlap": true,
          "iconSize": "15"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [3.1425, 39.8665625]
        }
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "icon": "information-15",
          "icon-allow-overlap": true,
          "iconSize": "15"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [3.14375, 39.869375]
        }
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "icon": "information-15",
          "icon-allow-overlap": true,
          "iconSize": "15"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [3.89, 40.08]
        }
      }, ]
    }
  });
  // Add a layer showing the places.
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'places',
    'type': 'symbol',
    'source': 'places',
    'layout': {
      'icon-image': 'information-15',
      'icon-size': 1,
      'icon-allow-overlap': true
    }
  });
```